# Precision of latitude / longitude in history

Tags: latitude-longitude, precision, history

I am looking to assign a likely precision value for a point based on the decade when the measurement was made. Lets say that in the 1910's the precision widely available would be to two decimal places. I wish to highlight museum records where the precision inferred by the number of decimal places in the latitude / longitude exceeds that which could have been measured at the time.

Comment: Precision depends on the equipment and education the surveyor has access to. Will you take this into account, too? E.g. there are highly precise surveys of [Saxony from the late 18th century](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meilenbl%C3%A4tter_von_Sachsen). The Swedes did a similarly precise [survey of Pomerania](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwedische_Landesaufnahme_von_Vorpommern) at the end of the 17th century.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a question in your Question, nor does this seem to be a GIS-centric problem.